# MySQL Syntax Error

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

This is my SQL Script

```
CREATE TABLE account_profile
(
accnt_id int NOT NULL ,
first_name varchar(255),
last_name varchar(255),
biography varchar(255),
date_joined DATE,
country varchar(255),
gender varchar(255),
screename varchar(255),
path varchar(255),
FOREIGN KEY (accnt_id) REFERENCES accounts(id)
)
```

it kept giving me this error
SQL query:

```
CREATE TABLE ac
```

MySQL said:

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 1
```

What does this specifically mean? what should I do? from my point of view the script is quite okay,I just can't pin point where's the error

Comment: you code is correct may be your `accounts` table is not exist.

Comment: Do you run this code alone or with other stuff (before this one)? I guess you are probably missing something in the previous line, like a `;`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure you're using the InnoDB engine.  The other engines do not support foreign keys.

```
CREATE TABLE account_profile
(
...
) ENGINE = INNODB;
```

Also check if the column `account_profile.accnt_id` matches the data type of `accounts.id` exactly.  The second column should have an index defined on it (a primary key will do.)

Comment: This is marked with phpMyAdmin, if you are using that tool it helps to run the show errors command:http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/show-errors.html

Answer (score 3):

I have tested your query and it works with me too. Do you have a query before creating the table `account_profile`? because if you do, try ***to check if the query before has been terminated by a semi-colon***. like this:

```
Create table TableName
(
    -- fields list
);  -- <== don't forget this before creating another table again.

CREATE TABLE account_profile
(
    accnt_id int NOT NULL ,
    first_name varchar(255),
    last_name varchar(255),
    biography varchar(255),
    date_joined DATE,
    country varchar(255),
    gender varchar(255),
    screename varchar(255),
    path varchar(255),
    FOREIGN KEY (accnt_id) REFERENCES accounts(id)
);  -- <== and also this.
```

*the error says near line 1.*

Answer (score 2):

Probably your table `account` does not exists :

```
FOREIGN KEY (accnt_id) REFERENCES accounts(id)
```

That's why you've got an error, the request is correct otherwise.

Comment: I have checked the query, its working fine and me also not have accounts table.